# Original Image Size

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

Using interop.powerpoint in VB.Net I am inserting an EMF file with the code:

```
' add picture shape to slide
            AvailableSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=file, LinkToFile:=MsoTriState.msoFalse, _
                SaveWithDocument:=MsoTriState.msoTrue, Left:=SlideHorizontalPosition, Top:=SlideVerticalPosition)

            ' save original image size
            mOriginalImageWidth = CurrentShape.Width
            mOriginalImageHeight = CurrentShape.Height
            ' if EMF then crop the bottom
            CurrentShape.PictureFormat.CropBottom = mCropValue
```

I have the original size saved before cropping.  However, if I'm using a selected image in a PPT file I didn't save, I can't figure out where the original image size is stored in the selected "shape" object (5.49" by 4.13" in the image below).  I assumed it would be in the PictureFormat somewhere.

dgp

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work but it's worth a shot (I can't test because I don't have Powerpoint).  After a little bit of research on the PictureFormat interface, it has a few members that might be useful to you.  I didn't exactly see anything that specified the picture's original size, but there were these four properties that seemed helpful: `CropLeft`, `CropRight`, `CropTop`, and `CropBottom`. They return the number of points cropped off each side respectively.  A way to get the original size of the object would be to add the `Width` to `CropLeft + CropRight` and add the Height to `CropTop + CropBottom`.  Try that and let me know if it works. Documentation is found here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.pictureformat_members(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.pictureformat_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Try getting the shape's `ScaleWidth` and `ScaleHeight` properties. I couldn't find it in the documentation, but awhile ago, I had a student work with me to create an application to format powerpoint presentations that were imported into microsoft word.  [Here's the code that dealt with the scale size of the shape.](https://github.com/abenavente406/DocEdit/blob/master/DocEdit/DocEdit/Form1.cs#L335-L336)

Comment: Anthony, yes, I have played with those values.  The problem is that the image may be scaled.  See the upper dialog, the image is scaled by 61%.  Adding the width to the left and right crop will get me to the scaled image size.  I can find nothing containing the scaling factor or original image size.  However, the dialog box knows the original size, so it must be available somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Set the shape's .ScaleHeight and .ScaleWidth to 1 to return it to the original size.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to the scale size properties.

Comment: Steve, yes, that will work in a destructive manner.  You are not passively retrieving the original size, you are dynamically changing the object back to the original size.  I looked at ScaleHeight.  What I'm looking for is a .ScaleHeight which will return the original size without changing the size.  Obviously, the system knows the original size, yet perhaps there is no interface into that information.

Comment: Non-destructively, if you record the shape's .Top, .Left, .Width and .Height properties before changing ScaleHeight/Width, then reset them later.  Or duplicate the shape, change the ScaleHeight/Width extract the information you need, then delete the duplicate shape. So far as I know, there's nothing in the OM that gives you the original size. This sort of clumsiness isn't at all unusual when you go to dance with PowerPoint, by the way.  There are all sorts of things you can do via UI that aren't exposed to code.